# how do i display the first hidden div with a specific class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have this situation ....

```
<div class="nested_fields"></div>
<div class="nested_fields" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="nested_fields"></div>
<div class="nested_fields"></div>
<div class="nested_fields" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="nested_fields" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="nested_fields" style="display: none;"></div>
```

I want to display show the first nested_fields div that is not hidden...so in the above situation it would be the second div with Jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".nested_fields:hidden").first().show();
```

or as $(".nested_fields") returns an array of objects you can also do:

```
$(".nested_fields:hidden")[0].show();
```

or using only selectors:

```
 $(".nested_fields:hidden:first").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.nested_fields:hidden:first')
```